# Jenkins maven projet build failed on fork during test

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm building maven project on Jenkins (version 2.263.4, not the last but not so far).

It's a git project with pipeline configuration and webhook from bitbucket when push is done on the project.

So when a developper create a branch and another one a pull request, i have 2 build in parallel. Domain test running in about 45min.

And sometimes(not always), i have this error :

```
Command was /bin/sh -c cd /jenkins/workspace/a-hub_test-plantage-jenkins_PR-1/server/project-core/project-core-domain && /jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk11/jdk-11.0.2+9/bin/java -Xmx1500M -jar /jenkins/workspace/a-hub_test-plantage-jenkins_PR-1/server/project-core/project-core-domain/target/surefire/surefirebooter15630998754365374145.jar /jenkins/workspace/a-hub_test-plantage-jenkins_PR-1/server/project-core/project-core-domain/target/surefire 2021-05-04T12-39-54_622-jvmRun1 surefire5846464826560071036tmp surefire_13691263758446667285tmp
 Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
14:46:13  [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
14:46:13  [ERROR]   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
14:46:13  [ERROR]   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
14:46:13  [ERROR]   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
```

If i re run the buildin error, it work.

I'm using maven-surefire 2.22.2.

I try to configure it following many thread on stackoverfow, but nothgin work. I try with forkMode none or something else, it work but i loose coverage because jaccoco need fork to work. So i'm stuck.

What can i do to help me to debug this problem?
I don't understand why build failed when another one is building because for me Jenkins work on different working folder, no? so why the problem appear when i'have multiple build in parallel?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I find an hs_err_pid.log in jenkins near source code and i see out of memory! i see that my test was launch with -Xmx1500Mo and problem occured when i launched multiple branch/pr, so jenkins use all of the memory and failed all build during fork...i decrease -Xmx and all seems to work.